# Calculating median of column "Balance" from table "Marketing"

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, median

I have a spark (scala) dataframe "Marketing" with approx 17 columns with 1 of them as "Balance". The data type of this column is Int. I need to find the median Balance. I can do upto arranging it in ascending order, but how to proceed after that? I have a given hint that the percentile function of scala can be used. I don't have any idea about this percentile function. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Median is the same thing as the 50th percentile. If you do not mind using hive functions you can do one of the following:

```
marketingDF.selectExpr("percentile(CAST(Balance AS BIGINT), 0.5) AS median")
```

If you do not need an exact figure you can look into using percentile_approx() instead.

Documentation for both functions is located [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)).